# Class inheritance, return object to a derived class

Tags: c#, .net

Here are following interface classes. I stumbled that upon trying to figure out how to write properly: SetObject method.
Here is what i want to achieve:

A) ITest is being injected from IoC container. That's why I need access to method allowing me to set object (SetObject)

B) In class: "Test" I would like to create object of: "IOtherInterface". Only class Test knows how to do it, however I don't want to point "directly" where that object has to be assigned, as it is now:

```
dataObject = new ObjectBuilder(userName);
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
public virtual IOtherInterface SetObject(string userName)
```

I would like abstract class to assign result type to: "dataObject"
Morover I would like to avoid writing two method in abstract class with the same input parameters. One which would call SetObject and another which would call object creation (and would have to pass the same parameter for the Test class to create object).

```
public interface ITest
{
  void SetObject(string userName);
}

public abstract class TestAbstract : ITest
{
  protected IOtherInterface dataObject;

  public TestAbstract()
  {
  }    

  public virtual void SetObject(string userName)
  {      
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }     
}

public class Test: TestAbstract
{      
  public Test () : base()
  {      
  }

  public override void SetObject(string userName)
  {
    dataObject = new ObjectBuilder(userName);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question and as I know, what you ask for is impossible with OOP at the level one class. You ask for how to a method of an abstract class can do a thing that only a subclass know how to do without creating another providing method and here it isn't necessary at all while it is an anti-pattern (duplication of code doing the same thing). Your virtual/override is addequate, it is the pattern. The method should be names `CreateObject`. You need to search in a design patterns if you can solve your goal. What do you want to do with `IOtherInterface SetObject(string userName)` ?

Comment: Generally I want class Test to create object and assign to TestAbstract's class: dataObject. Creating different object of IOtherInterface interface can let me to serve different functionality in abstract class.

Comment: Your code is right as-is. I don't understand your problem with it. `public virtual void SetObject(string userName)`  should be `public abstract void CreateObject(string userName)` while no implementation is on abstract class and it is not a setter method but a creator.

Comment: I know it works, but was only thinking hard if I can change something so that when someone is implementing: TestAbstract, would not need to know which field object should be assigned to but just return the object itself and abstract class should assign that where it should be.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you ask how to tell the compiler to infer the type of the object to create without any information about this type?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following:

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    IOtherInterface SetObject(string userName);
}
```

And implement it in a `Test` class, without creating an abstract mediator

Comment: TestAbstract publishes method of dataObject and I need it an abstract. But even with that, how can I assign the result of SetObject to dataObject property?